# Div stops being centered after adding border

Tags: css

So I centered a div totally fine, but after adding border it's no longer centered. It's positioned just like before, but now there is a border, so it's longer and the content is moved to the right by a border width. How to fix this?

Comment: Please add your code and screenshot of the issue

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Problem is obvious, doesnt require any code, Camille didn't need any code to give me a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your div :

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

So the border is part of the total object's width and height.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't understand why this isn't default in css.

Answer (score 0):

Can you send your css code for applying in div?

Please add this code to your div.

```
 .center { margin: auto; width: 50%; border: 3px solid #73AD21 }
```

Comment: That is not a good solution if I have to set certain properties to certain values.